# android proper implementation for deep linking

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have couple activities in one app.
There is a God Activity which is like a home page
and there are subsidiary activities like profiles.

for my understanding is, when we use deep linking, it should link to a specific content. for example, user X. and when people click the href, it should open user X's profile page.

My question is, when people click www.example.com/user-x
should i launch from the start of the app, and open profile page automatically after that. Or should i just open profile page directly.

opening from the start of the app may give me delay so user will not see what they want to see at once.opening directly will need to implement back key pressed handler to go to the main page ----i guess?

Also, is it better to create a stand alone activity to handle all the income urls to tell which activity should be start?

Comment: also i realized, instagram only open their app for you no matter where you are linking your content to. Medium has a back button on actionbar that pops the current activity

Answer (score 0):

- It should link directly to Activity which shows User X's profile and not redirect through your *GodActivity*
- No, a single activity should not be used to handle all redirects
- Don't make user go to *GodActivity* on pressing back. Back is supposed to remove activity from BackStack not add new ones
- Pressing the back button in ActionBar should take user to the Parent activity, *GodActivity* in your case

Comment: so the back button in action bar and the back button of your phone should act differently in this case? because in usual case, the user will go to the profile activity from home activity, and pushing the backbutton on action bar should act the same as the back button on your phone right??

Comment: No it shouldn't. ActionBar's back button is contextual, i.e., it's back for the app, not system. The navigation back button takes you back from where you came. See any Google app, like hangouts for example, it acts in a similar way.